# using requirejs within a firefox xul extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, requirejs, xul

I would like to use requirejs to manage my code within a firefox xul plugin, and I can't get it to find my modules.

I know that xul doesn't play nice with the `data-main` attribute, so I have my main.js script as a second script:

```
<script src="chrome://myPackage/content/require.js" type="application/x-javascript"></script>
<script src="chrome://myPackage/content/main.js" type="application/x-javascript"></script>
```

This successfully calls the script, and the require function is available within main.js, but when I run

```
require(['lib1'], function(lib1){
    alert(lib1.val1);
})
```

the alert never gets popped (lib1 is in the same directory as main.js).

I have tried this within and without setting the baseUrl as

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "chrome://myPackage/content/"
})
```

and it does not work either way.

Does anyone know how I can get require.js to look in the right place for my modules?

Addendum **

I added an error handling function and the error code returned is

```
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
```

I have loaded the test module into a normal web page successfully. This seems to confirm that the issue is path configuration (it also takes the 15 second timeout before failing)

Comment: Check Add-on SDK:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Add-ons/SDK

Answer (score 2):

Firebug seems to have a working requirejs version. But more importantly, they have a far better `mini-require.js` that will not pollute the shared global scope when used in overlays (if used correctly :p)

- https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/modules/require.js
- https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/modules/mini-require.js

I suggest you have a look at these implementations and also the code using it.

*Proactive warning*:
Please note, that if your add-on uses code that defines lots of new properties on the scope in overlays (`window`) either by defining global functions or variables or implicitly declaring variables within functions, then this may interfere with other code running in the same scope (the browser code itself and other add-ons). Besides, should you want to submit your add-on to addons.mozilla.org, then a reviewer might not give it public status if your add-on "pollutes" the global scope/namespace in the main overlay.

Comment: I had seen that firebug used requirejs, I did not realize that they were using their own flavor of it. Thanks for that catch.

Comment: trying it with mini-require doesn't fix the problem, but I will keep looking at firebug for a guide.